# Invariant Violation : Element type is invalid - React Native

Tags: react-native, react-redux

I have the bellow code in my App.js in my react native application.

```
import React from 'react';
import Provider from 'react-redux';
import {Text} from 'react-native';

const App: () => React$Node = () => {
  return (
    <Provider>
    <Text>hello</Text>
    </Provider>
  );
};
export default App;
```

It is not working and throws an error like as follows,

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change

```
import Provider from 'react-redux';
```

to

```
import {Provider} from 'react-redux';
```

After this, dont forget pass the store as a property to provider

```
 <Provider store={store}>
    <App />
 </Provider>
```